# ValueError: Cannot query “”: Must be “User” instance

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a story-sharing website where user can get to specific author's profile to see all the stories which the author wrote. However I am getting an error.

**ValueError at /storyauthor/1
Cannot query "yumin": Must be "User" instance.**

Here is my model:

```
class StoryAuthor(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a author.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular story-author instance.
        """

        return reverse('stories_by_author', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return self.user.username
```

view:

```
from django.views import generic

from django.views.generic import ListView

class StoryListbyAuthorView(generic.ListView):

"""
Generic class-based view for a list of stories posted by a particular 
StoryAuthor.
"""
model = Story
template_name = 'story/story_list_by_author.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return list of Story objects created by StoryAuthor (author id specified in URL)
    """
    id = self.kwargs['pk']
    target_author=get_object_or_404(StoryAuthor, pk = id)
    return Story.objects.filter(author=target_author)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Add StoryAuthor to context so they can be displayed in the template
    """
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(StoryListbyAuthorView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Get the storyauthor object from the "pk" URL parameter and add it to the context
    context['author'] = get_object_or_404(StoryAuthor, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.story_list, name='story_list'),
    url(r'^storyauthor/(?P<pk>\d+)$', 
    views.StoryListbyAuthorView.as_view(), name='stories_by_author'),
]
```

Comment: can you provide more info and post some views from which the error appears?

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: I just added my views as well as urls

Comment: I found out the problem! The original code was like this 

class Story(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='storys')

So I just revised it like this
    author = models.ForeignKey(StoryAuthor, related_name='storys')

Comment: Hei @YuminHuang - can you post your solution as an answer? It's perfectly fine to do that and accept it. It'll be helpful for other people : )

Answer (score 0):

as @yumin-huang said in comments:

> I found out the problem!
>
> The original code was like this
>
> ```
> class Story(models.Model): author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='storys')
> ```
>
> So I just revised it like this
>
> ```
> author = models.ForeignKey(StoryAuthor, related_name='storys')
> ```